# Microsoft Dynamics crm api-update child company parentaccountid

Tags: php, api, dynamics-crm

Trying to update a account _parentaccountid_value.

The request url is:
    https://alliedmodulartemp.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(accountid)

Method:PATCH

Data:
{
  "_parentaccountid_value@odata.bind": "/accounts(accountid)"

}

But the error is,"message": "An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A property '_parentaccountid_value' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value is declared to be of type 'Edm.Guid'.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need _parentaccountid_value rather you need _parentaccountid. Try below code and it shall work.

```
Data: { "_parentaccountid@odata.bind": "/accounts(accountid)"

}
```